# WPF Prism CompositeCommand disables button

Tags: wpf, prism

I have two commands that I want to trigger via a button click.  So I've created a `CompositeCommand`, registered my two commands with it, and bound to my button.  My commands are `DelegateCommands`.

The problem is that the button is disabled and I can't enable it.

I've tried adding trivial `CanExecute` methods to the `DeleteCommands`, but that didn't fix it.

I've tried setting `monitorCommandActivity` to true in the `CompositeCommand` constructor.

I thought maybe it was disabling because my `DelegateCommands` have parameters and a `CompositeCommand` doesn't seem to be able to take any `CommandParameters`, but I eliminated the parameters in the `DelegateCommands` and that didn't fix the problem.

View.xaml:

```
    <TextBlock Text="Theme:" />
    <telerik:RadComboBox x:Name="_themeComboBox"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding ThemeList}"
                         DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTheme, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <telerik:RadButton Content="Apply"
                       Command="{Binding ThemeApplyAndSaveCommand}" />
```

ViewModel.cs:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel(ILogger logger, ...)
    {
        ThemeList = _userSettingsService.GetThemeList();

        // Configure the theme Apply button to both select and save the theme
        ThemeApplyAndSaveCommand.RegisterCommand(ThemeApplyCommand);
        ThemeApplyAndSaveCommand.RegisterCommand(ThemeSaveCommand);

        // Activate the user's preferred theme
        SelectedTheme = _userSettingsService.GetThemePreference(securityContext.User);
        ThemeApplyCommand.Execute();

        logger.Debug("    ThemeApplyCommand.CanExecute: {canExecute}", ThemeApplyCommand.CanExecute());
        logger.Debug("    ThemeSaveCommand.CanExecute: {canExecute}", ThemeSaveCommand.CanExecute());
        logger.Debug("    ThemeApplyAndSaveCommand.CanExecute: {canExecute}", ThemeApplyAndSaveCommand.CanExecute(null));
    }


    public CompositeCommand ThemeApplyAndSaveCommand => new CompositeCommand();

    public DelegateCommand ThemeApplyCommand => new DelegateCommand(ExecuteThemeApplyCommand);

    public DelegateCommand ThemeSaveCommand => new DelegateCommand(ExecuteThemeSaveCommand);

    private void ExecuteThemeApplyCommand()
    {
        ...
    }

    private void ExecuteThemeSaveCommand()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to register `DelegateCommand`s to a `CompositeCommand` using the `RegisterCommand` method. Directly adding them to the `RegisteredCommands` collection does not work, as it returns a new collection instance each time.

```
var compositeCommand = new CompositeCommand();
compositeCommand.RegisterCommand(MyDelgateCommand);
compositeCommand.RegisterCommand(MyOtherDelegateCommand);
```

A `CompositeCommand` only returns `true` for `CanExecute`, if **all active** commands can execute. You have to make sure to call `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` when the registered commands should update their activity, so the composite command can reevaluate its activity, too.

Monitoring the command activity is something completely different. Views or view models in Prism can implement `IActiveAware` to know when they are activated and deactivated in a region. `DelegateCommands` implement this interface too, so they can also be activated and deactivated with their corresponding view model. If you do not explicitly enable monitoring command activity, commands will be treated as if they are active.

Imagine a command to save the active document in a tab control. You could register save commands of the tabs to a common save `CompositeCommand`, but activate them only if they are on the active tab. In that case, monitoring the activity of the commands will only consider active commands for `CanExecute` and will execute only them, when the command is invoked.

---

Update on your posted code. The corresponding command properties return new commands each time. Initialize the composite command and the other commands in the constructor.

```
public ViewModel(ILogger logger, ...)
{
   ThemeList = _userSettingsService.GetThemeList();

   // Configure the theme Apply button to both select and save the theme
   ThemeApplyAndSaveCommand = new CompositeCommand();
   ThemeApplyCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteThemeApplyCommand);
   ThemeSaveCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteThemeSaveCommand);

   ThemeApplyAndSaveCommand.RegisterCommand(ThemeApplyCommand);
   ThemeApplyAndSaveCommand.RegisterCommand(ThemeSaveCommand);

   // ...the rest of the constructor code.
}

public CompositeCommand ThemeApplyAndSaveCommand { get; }

public DelegateCommand ThemeApplyCommand { get; }

public DelegateCommand ThemeSaveCommand { get; }
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I did use `RegisterCommand()`.  I'm not even interested in monitoring executability (or whatever you call it).  This command is always executable.

Comment: Do I have to manually make the commands active?  This isn't making any sense to me why the button would become disabled just my replacing my button's command with a composite command that wraps it.

Comment: @MattGregory If you do not explicitly enable command monitoring, all commands will be treated as if they are active. If you just create two delegate commands without any `CanExecute` or always `true` and register them to a composite command, it will work as expected, the button will be enabled.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I would expect, but it doesn't work.  I register the `DelegateCommand`s with the `CompositeCommand`, and when I log the result of `CanExecute` on each of these, immediately after, the two `DelegateCommand`s' return `true` and the `CompositeCommand`'s returns `false`.  I think I'm going to give up now on CompositeCommands.

Comment: @MattGregory Can you post a minimal example of your code and binding in XAML?

Comment: @MattGregory I updated the answer. I can reproduce and resolve the issue.

Comment: Oh! I know why!  Because every time you access the properties where I used the arrow operator, they return a new object!

Answer (score 0):

As @thatguy pointed out, the issue is that you were creating new commands every time you accessed the properties.

If you want to keep the construction in line with your properties, try changing

```
public CompositeCommand ThemeApplyAndSaveCommand => new CompositeCommand();

public DelegateCommand ThemeApplyCommand => new DelegateCommand(ExecuteThemeApplyCommand);

public DelegateCommand ThemeSaveCommand => new DelegateCommand(ExecuteThemeSaveCommand);
```

to

```
public CompositeCommand ThemeApplyAndSaveCommand {get;} = new CompositeCommand();

public DelegateCommand ThemeApplyCommand {get;} = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteThemeApplyCommand);

public DelegateCommand ThemeSaveCommand {get;} = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteThemeSaveCommand);
```